# AJAX Internal Server Error 500 Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

I am using ajax to push my data in database in laravel 5.4 because i don't want to refresh the page or redirect somewhere when i push data and i get this error internal server error 500. I am new to ajax btw, maybe the error is so simple yet i don't know. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code in my ajax.

```
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
$.ajax({
      method : "post",
      url : '../../myroute',
      data : { '_token' : CSRF_TOKEN, 'varForController' : varInJavaScript, 'varForController' : varInJavaScript, 'varForController' : varInJavaScript,
      },
      success: function(json){
        // console.log(json);
      },
      error: function(a,b,c)
      {
        console.log(b);
      }
    });
```

and here is my route

```
Route::post('myroute', 'MyController@functionInController');
```

Comment: 500 internal server error, as the name implies, is a server error. Check your server's error logs

Comment: @PatrickEvans ohh I see, but where do I find that error log?

Answer (score 0):

```
  var CSRF_TOKEN = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

  $.ajax({
       method : "post",
       url : '../../myroute',
       data : { '_token' : CSRF_TOKEN, 'varForController' : varInJavaScript, 'varForController' : varInJavaScript, 'varForController' : varInJavaScript,
  },
  success: function(json){
    // console.log(json);
  },
  error: function(a,b,c)
  {
    console.log(b);
  }
});
```

Try this code in your blade file.

Comment: still an internal server error. I tried to console.log() all data. the CSRF_TOKEN, and all all variables.. it all has values. but it seems that if i dd() in my controller in laravel nothing happens. my route is the same as in the url and route in my web.php is also correct that it is pointing into that function in the controller

Comment: Try in your blade file